# string.Format fails at runtime with array of integers

Tags: c#, arrays, string-formatting

Consider `string.Format()` whose parameters are a string and, among others in the overload list, an `object[]` or many objects.

This statement succeeds:

```
string foo = string.Format("{0} {1}", 5, 6);
```

as does this:

```
object[] myObjs = new object[] {8,9};
string baz = string.Format("{0} and {1}", myObjs;
```

as does an array of strings:

```
string[] myStrings = new string[] {"abc", "xyz"};
string baz = string.Format("{0} {1}", myStrings);
```

It seems that the integers, when specified individually, can be boxed or coerced to type `object`, which in turn is coerced to a string.

This statement fails at **runtime**.

```
int[] myInts = new int[] {8,9};
string bar = string.Format("{0} and {1}", myInts);
```

> Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

- Why doesn't or can't the int array be coerced or boxed to an `object[]` or `string[]`?
- Out of a small bit of curiosity, why doesn't the compiler catch this?

Comment: Finally found a satisfying solution for this issue, which I am happy to share  ... [please check it out.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50236176/1016343)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The call fails with the same reason the following will also fail:

```
string foo = string.Format("{0} {1}", 5);
```

You are specifying two arguments in the `format` but only specifying one object.

The compiler does not catch it because `int[]` is passed as an object which is a perfectly valid argument for the function.

Also note that array covariance does not work with value types so you cannot do:

```
object[] myInts = new int[] {8,9};
```

However you can get away with:

```
object[] myInts = new string[] { "8", "9" };
string bar = string.Format("{0} {1}", myInts);
```

which would work because you would be using the `String.Format` overload that accepts an `object[]`.

Comment: ão: thanks for this answer. I've updated teh question to include the success of `string.Format()` with a `string[]`. Is that any different from the `int[]`?

Comment: @p.campbell, see my update about array covariance not being supported in value types.

Comment: So you are saying that `int[]` is being passed as an object instead of as an array or object array but `object[]` will be passed as an array?

Comment: @Jack, a value type array would use the overload that accepts an `object` while a reference type array would use the overload that accepts an `object[]`.

Answer (score 3):

Your call gets translated into this:

```
string foo = string.Format("{0} {1}", myInts.ToString());
```

which results in this string:

```
string foo = "System.Int32[] {1}";
```

So as the {1} doesn't have a parameter, it throws an exception

Answer (score 2):

I think the concept you are having an issue with is why `int[]` isn't cast to `object[]`.  Here's an example that shows why that would be bad

```
int[] myInts = new int[]{8,9};
object[] myObjs = (object[])myInts;
myObjs[0] = new object();
```

The problem is that we just added an object into a int array.

So what happens in your code is that `myInts` is cast to `object` and you don't have a second argument to fill in the `{1}`

Answer (score 1):

This is quite an old question, but I recently got the same issue. And I haven't seen an answer that works for me, so I'll share the solution I found.

- *Why doesn't or can't the int array be coerced or boxed to an object[] or string[]?* 
   Why it isn't boxed, I don't know. But it **can be boxed explicitly,** see solution below.
- *Why doesn't the compiler catch this?* 
   Because the compiler misinterprets the situation: The type isn't exactly an object array, so it doesn't know what to do with it and decides to perform a `.ToString()` on the int array, which returns one single parameter containing the type name rather than the parameter list itself. It doesn't do that with a string array, because the target type is already a string - but with any other kind of array the same issue happens (for example `bool[]`). 
  Consider `var arr1 = new int[]{1,2};` with `string.Format("{0}", arr1)`: As long as you have only `{0}` in the format string, you get only the type name `"System.Int32[]"` back (and no exception occurs). 
  If you have more placeholders, e.g. `string.Format("{0}{1}", arr1)`, then the exception occurs - because `arr1` is misinterpreted as *one* parameter - and for the compiler, *a 2<sup>nd</sup> one* is missing.
   But what I think is a conceptional bug is that you can't convert `arr1`, i.e. if you try to do `(object[])arr1`- you're getting:

  > CS0030 Cannot convert type 'int[]' to 'object[]'

**Solution:**

Filling in each element of the int array is not a solution that works for me, because in my project I am creating a format template string dynamically during runtime containing the `{0}...{n}` - hence I need to pass an array to `String.Format`.

So I found the following **workaround.** I created a generic helper function (which of course could be an extension method too if you prefer):

```
// converts any array to object[] and avoids FormatException
object[] Convert<T>(T[] arr)
{
    var obj = new List<object>();
    foreach (var item in arr)
    {
        obj.Add((object)item);
    }   
    return obj.ToArray();
}
```

Now if you try that in the example below which is showing up the FormatException:

```
// FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero 
//                  and less than the size of the argument list
var arr1 = (new int[] { 1, 2 });
string.Format("{0}{1}{0}{1}", arr1).Dump();
```

> **Fix:** Use   **`Convert(arr1)`**   as *2<sup>nd</sup> parameter* for   `string.Format(...)`   as shown below:

```
// Workaround: This shows 1212, as expected
var arr1 = (new int[] { 1, 2 });
string.Format("{0}{1}{0}{1}", Convert(arr1)).Dump();
```

**Try example as [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TR5MgR)**

**Conclusion:**
As it seems, the .NET runtime really misinterprets the parameter by applying a `.ToString()` to it, if it is not already of type `object[]`. The `Convert` method gives the runtime no other choice than to do it the right way, because it returns the expected type. I found that an explicit type conversion did not work, hence the helper function was needed.

**Note:** If you invoke the method many times in a loop and you're concerned about speed, you could also convert everything to a string array which is probably most efficient:

```
// converts any array to string[] and avoids FormatException
string[] ConvertStr<T>(T[] arr)
{
    var strArr = new string[arr.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        strArr[i]=arr[i].ToString();
    }
    return strArr;
}
```

This is working as well. To convert from a different datatype, such as a dictionary, you can simply use

```
string[] Convert<K,V>(Dictionary<K,V> coll)
{
    return ConvertStr<V>(coll.Values.ToArray());
}
```

---

**Update:** With string interpolation, another short way to solve it is:

```
var baz = string.Format("{0} and {1}", myInts.Select(s => $"{s}").ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

Short way to make it work (not the most optimal though):

```
int[] myInts = new int[] { 8, 9 };
string[] myStrings = Array.ConvertAll(myInts, x => x.ToString());
// or using LINQ
// string[] myStrings = myInts.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
bar = string.Format("{0} and {1}", myStrings);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string.Format is expecting 2 arguments ({0} and {1}). You are only supplying 1 argument (the int[]). You need something more like this:

```
string bar = string.Format("{0} and {1}", myInts[0], myInts[1]);
```

The compiler does not notice the problem because the format string is evaluated at runtime. IE The compiler doesn't know that {0} and {1} mean there should be 2 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
string bar = string.Format("{0} and {1}", myInts[0], myInts[1]);
```

The compiler doesn't catch it because it doesn't evaluate your format string.

The example you gave up top doesn't match what you're trying to do down below... you provided two {} and two arguments, but in the bottom one you only provided one argument.