# help me in asp.net string.format

Tags: asp.net

I am getting error on following lines of code...plz help.

Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

```
    string order1= string.Format ("exec a_add_user '{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}'",TextBox_first_name.Text ,TextBox_last_name.Text ,TextBox_user_name.Text ,TextBox_password.Text ,DropDownList_telephone_code.SelectedValue  +TextBox_telephone_no.Text ,DropDownList_mobile_code.SelectedValue +TextBox_mobile_no.Text ,RadioButtonList_gender.SelectedValue ,DropDownList_country.SelectedValue ,DropDownList_city.SelectedValue ,TextBox_address.Text);
```

Comment: Learn to use a debugger. This is not a suitable question for SO.

Comment: This question _has_ enough informations to diagnose the problem and it _can_ be reproduced even if it's not a good question since it has many duplicates ( [such as](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258187/string-format-fails-at-runtime-with-array-of-integers) ).

Comment: You are passing 10 arguments but try to access `{10}` which, is zero based, argument 11.

Answer (score 2):

You're specifying 11 format items but have 10 strings you're trying to append.